# laravel 5.3 login authenticate failed issue

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am using the below code to encrypt email in laravel 5.3 . I have stored this encrypted email value in the database.

```
use Encryptable;

protected $encryptable = [
     'firstname', 'lastname','email','phone'

];
```

When I login I am using the below code to encrypt the email that I entered in the login form. Every time the encryption gives different value and hence when i compare this value with database value the comparision fails and not able to login. Please let advice me what i am missing here.

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => Crypt::encrypt(Input::get('email')), 'password' => Input::get('password') ])) {

    // Authentication passed...
    return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
} 
else{        

    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors([
            $this->username() => Lang::get('auth.failed'),
        ]);

}
```

Comment: The encryption value works like this by design. It uses an initialization vector to ensure that the encrypted value has some randomness. Why encrypt the email address anyway? surely its the password you want to "encrypt". A message digest, or hash is used for this purpose. In laravel you would use $password = Hash::make('secret');

Comment: You could also hash the email if you don't want it human readable in the database. This would solve your problem but as the hash is a  one way process the original plain text email address would be unrecoverable.

Comment: If you want to do this you'll have to decrypt the email addresses first, like @DaveCarruthers said you should look into hashing the email address along side encrypting it.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** the reason your example doesn't work is because if you run `Crypt::encrypt(Input::get('email'))` twice you get two different decryptable strings that cannot be compared.

To complement my comment you'll have to save both the email hash and encrypted email value on your user object, then you'll be able to lookup/login the user using the hashed value and decrypt the email address when needed by your software (i.e. displaying on account page, forgot password email etc.)

So you'll have `encrypted_email` and `email` lookup the Email as a hash

```
$emailHash= Hash::make(Input::get('email'));
$password = Input::get('password');
Auth::attempt(['email'=> $emailHash, 'password' => $password]);
```

And if you want to display or use the email address you'll decrypt the `encrypted_email` field on the user object.

```
$email = decrypt($user->encryptedEmail);
```